# Android Wrong Date

Tags: android, date

I want to get the current date and the date exactly one month previous. For example if today is 1/13/2014, I want to get today's date, 1/13/2014 and the day one month ago, 12/13/2013. For some reason, I am only getting the older date and not today's date.

[image: Bad Dates]

Do you know why that might be?

**Main code**

```
//define Report Start and End Dates
     if(startYear == 0)
     {
        // Get due date
        Calendar curDate = Calendar.getInstance();
        Calendar defaultStart = curDate;
        defaultStart.set(curDate.get(Calendar.YEAR), curDate.get(Calendar.MONTH)-1, curDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        String curYear = ((Integer)curDate.get(Calendar.YEAR)).toString();
        String curMonth = ((Integer)(curDate.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1)).toString();
        String curDay = ((Integer)curDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).toString();
        if(curDate.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1 < 10)
            curMonth = "0"+((Integer)(curDate.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1)).toString();
        String defaultYear = ((Integer)defaultStart.get(Calendar.YEAR)).toString();
        String defaultMonth = ((Integer)(defaultStart.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1)).toString();
        String defaultDay = ((Integer)defaultStart.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).toString();
        if(defaultStart.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1 < 10)
            defaultMonth = "0"+((Integer)(defaultStart.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1)).toString();
        reportEndDate = curYear+"-"+curMonth+"-"+curDay;
        reportStartDate = defaultYear+"-"+defaultMonth+"-"+defaultDay;
     }
     else
     {
         reportStartDate = startMonth+"/"+startYear;
         reportEndDate = endMonth+"/"+endYear;
     }

     TextView startDateText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.startDateText);
     startDateText.setText(reportStartDate);
     TextView endDateText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.endDateText);
     endDateText.setText(reportEndDate);
```

**xml layout file**

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/startDateText"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
             android:textSize="20sp"
             android:textStyle="bold"
             android:textColor="@color/mediumDarkGray"
             android:text="XXXX-XX-XX"
             />

        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:textSize="20sp"
             android:textStyle="bold"
             android:textColor="@color/mediumDarkGray"
             android:text=" to " />

        <TextView android:id="@+id/endDateText"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
             android:textSize="20sp"
             android:textStyle="bold"
             android:textColor="@color/mediumDarkGray"
             android:text="XXXX-XX-XX"
             />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set the calendar 1 month back, but then added 1 to both the start month and the end month (curMonth and defaultMonth)

This happened because you are using the same instance of Calendar for both curDate and defaultStart. You need:

```
Calendar defaultStart = Calendar.getInstance();
```

and you are fine.

Comment: If I'm getting a new instance, isn't the time technically different by a very small amount? If for whatever reason my user was using it exactly at 11:59pm, could it possibly have two different dates?

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding Jim's answer a little. It's when you set defaultStart = curDate. You only have one calendar instance there, and you have defaultStart and curDate both pointing to that same object. When you make a change on either of those variable names, it effects the object that both are pointing to.

So when you go curDate month + 1, that change happens to defaultStart as well because both curDate and defaultStart are effectively just pointers to the same object.

Comment: No I understood that part. What I'm asking is if each time I call `Calendar.getInstance()` doesn't it get a different time? Therefore, if that method is called at exactly midnight, could it have two different days?

Comment: Even though you marked as the correct answer, I will add that after getting the second instance, you could write logic to check for cross-midnight events, or simply use one to reset the other before adding/subtracting a month. Like: curDate.setTime(defaultStart.getTime())

Answer (score 0):

Rather than all this messing around why not use the built in `add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -1)`
Also you could use the `SimpleDateFormat` to format your Dates.